# Windows 10 laptop > Reset this PC > now stuck in boot loop

Tags: windows-10, boot, drivers, windows-installation, nvme

**TLDR:**  This laptop is a Dell Latitude 5420 with an NVMe SSD drive -- and apparently Windows has lost the driver for that drive? It can't boot, and I can't (re)install Windows on it without that driver. I do not have any such driver.

**What I have:** For business reasons, this laptop needed a reset. No biggie: Windows 10 offers the built-in functionality to "Reset this PC". I did just that.

**Problem:** Something must have gone wrong while Windows was resetting/reinstalling itself, because the laptop is now stuck in a boot loop. I see the **circling dots for a little while, and then it reboots** -- endlessly.

**What Ive tried:**

1. Force the computer into recovery mode: force power off during boot, three boots in a row, then it *should* boot into Recovery. But it does not, it just resumes its boot loop.
2. I've used a separate computer to create Win10 installation media on a USB stick, and go to Repair. It says it can't repair. It also says there's no recovery partition, and no system snapshots to roll back to.
3. Using the same USB installer, I've tried to simply reinstall Windows 10, but that also runs afoul because it seems the disk drive needs some special driver that I do not have.

**How can I get this computer to boot??**

> Load driver
> A media driver your computer needs is missing. This could
> be a DVD, USB or Hard disk driver. If you have a CD, DVD, or USB flash
> drive with the driver on it, please insert it now. Note: If the
> installation media for Windows is in the DVD drive or on a USB drive,
> you can safely remove it for this step.

BIOS says I have this disk:

> Type = 256GB PM991 a NVMe Samsung 256GB
> Device = PM991 a NVMe Samsung 256GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading the Intel RST drivers (unzipped) from here on the flash drive and use **Load driver** in the installer to find and load them:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000058724/memory-and-storage/intel-optane-memory.html

### Step by step:

1. Go to https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19512/intel-rapid-storage-technology-driver-installation-software-with-intel-optane-memory-10th-and-11th-gen-platforms.html and click on **Download SetupRST.exe** which will download a file with the name ***SetupRST.exe***
2. Extract driver files from SetupRST.exe:

   - Open a terminal in the directory where the downloaded SetupRST.exe is, by right-clicking the directory and selecting "***Open in Terminal***" or "***Open PowerShell here***"
   - Enter the following command: `./SetupRST.exe -extractdrivers SetupRST_extracted`
3. Copy all driver files from the new **SetupRST_extracted** folder to the Windows installation USB
4. Start the Windows installation, and during the Setup on the ***Where do you want to install Windows?*** screen, click **Load Driver** to install the storage drive

   - Follow the prompts and browse to the location of the installation files that were copied earlier to the USB
   - Select the appropriate ‘.inf’ file (64 or 32 bit).  If a supported controller is detected there will be no error message (if one doesn't install/help, try one by one all the drivers there)
   - Follow prompts to continue and complete the installation

Comment: There are 2 files to download, and even though the page you linked to says it's ZIP format, it is in fact EXE files that are installers that very clearly state "you will NOT be able to uninstall this". I don't want to install this on *this* computer. Is there no ZIP file?

Comment: On the page it says ***For RST File Extraction (.zip file creation), refer to section 6.3 of the Readme file: Pre-Installation of Intel® RST driver using the Load Driver method.*** which provides the instructions

Comment: Thank you, found it and extracted the files. Both of the RST packages contain *exactly identical* files, though.

Comment: It seems that both of the links indeed lead to the same. Anyhow have you tried loading those in the Windows install?

Comment: I'm not successful. I copied all files to the USB stick, but the Windows installer did not accept them at the step where it asks for a driver. I manually selected one, one by one, until it seemed satisfied with one of them: "Intel RST VMD Controller 9A0B (iaStorVD.inf)" -- it's installing now, let's see what happens.

Comment: "I'm **not** successful" or "**it's installing**"?

Comment: That was an indication that I got past the hurdle but was not convinced that it worked. Now, a day later, I can confirm that it did indeed work.